# In SQL Azure how can I create a read only user

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, azure-sql-database

I would like to create an SQL Azure user and grant her read-only access on a handful of DBs, what script can I use to achieve this?

Comment: FYI http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee336235.aspx

Answer (score 99, accepted):

A pure TSQL script is super messy, SQL Azure disables the `USE` command, so you are stuck opening connections to each DB you need to give the user read access.

This is the gist of the pattern.

In Master DB:

```
CREATE LOGIN reader WITH password='YourPWD';
-- grant public master access
CREATE USER readerUser FROM LOGIN reader;
```

In each target DB (requires a separate connection)

```
CREATE USER readerUser FROM LOGIN reader;
EXEC sp_addrolemember 'db_datareader', 'readerUser';
```

Comment: Why is there a "CREATE USER..." in master DB? In all docs I looked at, it only says you have to create user in target DB...Just curious...

Comment: Ancient answer and old comment, but for anyone interested... I think he's included the create user in master DB so the user (readerUser) can login to the server instance via Management Studio - if the user doesn't exist under master, they won't be able to use SQL authentication in Management Studio to sign in.

Comment: Grant permissions at object level or **for selected tables** check [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3998634/sql-server-2008-how-do-i-grant-privileges-to-a-username) and [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11086967/how-to-permit-a-sql-server-user-to-insert-update-delete-data-but-not-alter-sche) , hope helps.

Answer (score 4):

OR... Use the **Azure User Management console - AUMC** to manage the Logins and Users.

It's a open source project available on codeplex [AUMC.codeplex.com](http://AUMC.codeplex.com)

> **Project Description**
>
> Azure User Management Console - AUMC is a User
>   Graphic Interface (GUI) that manages the users and logins of an Azure
>   SQL database.  The tool is simply converting your action into T-SQL
>   commands and execute them on the Azure SQL Database.

A quick simple tool with a user interface! Don

Enjoy!

Comment: It's a little spooky to plug your database credentials into apps just downloaded from the internet ... just saying ...

Answer (score 1):

You can create new user without creating login on **master** DB (which is require make a separate connection)

```
CREATE USER user1 WITH password='<Strong_Password>';
```

https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/documentation/articles/sql-database-manage-logins/

Comment: In 2023 this is a correct answer. Maybe back in 2015 it wasn't.