# Cannot login with read-only user to SQL Azure database

Tags: sql, azure, azure-sql-database

I've followed the answer to this question: [In SQL Azure how what script can I use to create a read only user](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2777422/in-sql-azure-how-what-script-can-i-use-to-create-a-read-only-user)

I've completed all the steps successfully on the correct server. However, when I try to login to the Azure database, I'm getting the following error:

```
Login failed for user 'readerUser'.
This session has been assigned a tracing ID of '(some guid)'.
Provide this tracing ID to customer support when you need assistance.
```

I've tried this in both my ASP.NET website and in my LINQPad, they both give the same error (with different GUIDs). I am trying to connect to the exact same server as my primary login, which can connect perfectly.

I've also checked `sys.sysusers` system view and `readerUser` is there as a login.

What could be the reason?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After trying many combinations (and learning better about users, logins, and roles on SQL Azure) I've figured out the issue:

I was trying to login with `readerUser`, which is just a database user, and I should instead have logged in with the login instance, hence `reader` (as followed by the answer at the question that I've linked). I've tried logging in with `reader` and it worked perfectly: logging in, `SELECT`ing anything I want, but not able to write/alter/delete anything.